# Asset Tracking in Ethereum or Monax DB

Tags: solidity, monax

Lets say an asset is created as a smart contract instance. Now each asset id (i.e. contract address) is stored in a manager contract. Now the status of the asset changes during the course of the workflow.

In this case what is the best way to track the state changes of the asset.

Don't want to have an audit kind of contract to track asset state changes. Rather want to somehow utilize the platform to fetch the previous states of the asset contract instance by providing the asset id (i.e. contract address)

Comment: do you need this info offchain?

Comment: Well the idea is to find the tractability from the platform itself